# Angular httpClient get users from an Array of JSON using Longitude Latitude Haversine formula

Tags: php, json, angular, typescript, httpclient

I have list of users in a  JSON file

```
[
  {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Maurise",
      "last_name": "Shieldon",
      "latitude": 34.003135,
      "longitude": -117.7228641
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Bendix",
      "last_name": "Halgarth",
      "latitude": -2.9623869,
      "longitude": 104.7399789
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Meghan",
      "last_name": "Southall",
      "latitude": "15.45033",
      "longitude": "44.12768"
  },
  {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "Sidnee",
      "last_name": "Silwood",
      "latitude": -26.94087,
      "longitude": 29.24905
  },
  {
      "id": 5,
      "first_name": "Rosita",
      "last_name": "Ferrulli",
      "latitude": 33.5719791,
      "longitude": -84.3396421
  }]
```

I am using Haversine formula to calculate distance so that i can only get users of certain LAT and LONG values this method is in my `api.service.ts` class.

```
   getDistanceFromLatLon(lat1: number, lon1: number, lat2: number, lon2: number): number {
    var deg2Rad = deg => {
      return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    var r = 3959; // Radius of the earth in miles
    var dLat = deg2Rad(lat2 - lat1);
    var dLon = deg2Rad(lon2 - lon1);
    var a =
      Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(deg2Rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2Rad(lat2)) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = r * c; // Distance in miles
    return d;
  }
```

Then in my `app.component.ts` file i can call JSON Array which gives me list of all users in `data.json` file from my list of users above.

```
getUsers() {
this.httpClient.get('/assets/users.json').pipe(map(data => data as Array<Users>))
      .subscribe(result => { console.log(result)}
```

After i receive list of all users from my JSON file. I am trying to run the JSON `result` Array through the `getDistanceFromLatLon` method so that only users with  `LONDON_LAT` and `LONDON_LONG` can displayed

```
 //Latitude and longitude of London
  LONDON_LAT = 51.509865;
  LONDON_LONG = -0.118092;
  miles;

const distance = this.apiService.getDistanceFromLatLon(result['latitude'], result['longitude'], 
this.LONDON_LAT, this.LONDON_LONG);
        if (distance <= this.miles) {
          this.UsersByRadius = result;
        }
      });
}
```

After compiling through the  `.getDistanceFromLatLon` my `this.UsersByRadius = result` is empty and i am not getting any users.
I am basically trying to replicate this [PHP application](https://github.com/qasimahmed321/bpdts/blob/master/classes/api.php) in my angular app. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Angular SPA are usually generated client-side. So all the mathematical calculations (a single division operation has a heavy overhead, not to mention all the trig functions) will be heavy overload when dealing with large array sets. You should consider doing it server-side.
2. You are retreiving an array. So you need to loop through each of them to call the function.

```js
getUsers() {
  this.httpClient.get('/assets/users.json').pipe(
    map(data => data as Array<Users>)
  ).subscribe(result => { 
    console.log(result);
    result.forEach(item => {
      const distance = this.apiService.getDistanceFromLatLon(item['latitude'], item['longitude'], this.LONDON_LAT, this.LONDON_LONG);
      if (distance <= this.miles) {
        this.UsersByRadius.push({
          id: item['id'],   
          first_name: item['first_name'],
          last_name: item['last_name'],   
          latitude: item['latitude'],   
          longitude: item['longitute'],
          city: 'London'
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it seems to be failing at if statement  ``` if (distance <= this.miles)```  it seems that ```getDistanceFromLatLon``` is not compiling result is still empty :(

Comment: I've edited the answer to move the `const distance` inside the loop. But still there is an issue here. The `this.UsersByRadius` will be updated individually for each item of the array. You need to consider making `UsersByRadius` either an array or a property of the incoming object.

Comment: Thanks. ```UserByRadius``` is actually an Array  ```UsersByRadius: Array<Users>;```I am not sure what property of  ```miles``` should be, the ```result``` seems to be printing all the ```users``` instead of ```UsersByRadius```

Comment: have done so. it is i still printing all the users ```UsersByRadius = [];```

Comment: You need to push the object to the `UsersByRadius` array, I've modified the code. But still I don't see the `Users` type definition. Without it I can't say what exactly you need to push to the array. For now I've written the placeholder *object of type Users* in the answer. It should be replaced with the actual object.

Comment: So ```Users``` is ```export class Users {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  city: string;
}```

Comment: sorry still confused how i need to push User objects. :(

Comment: @Sammy: I've updated the code, but it's still unclear what you're trying to achieve. Try to create a Stackblitz.

Comment: that did the trick, thanks a million. I got the result i wanted.

Comment: If you're new to Angular, I'd recommend you to go through tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces some of the basics.